# Отображение графика Google Chart по нажатию кнопки Ajax или JQuery на Asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Есть такой график от гугла, как Google Tool Chart. Но есть с ним одна загвоздка.  Вот как его  реализовать. Вот контроллер:

```
public class ChartController : Controller
{
     public JsonResult CreateChart()
    {
        var result = new List<PieChartItem>();
        result.Add(new PieChartItem { Name = "Ukraine", Value = 5 });
        result.Add(new PieChartItem { Name = "Russia", Value = 6 });
        result.Add(new PieChartItem { Name = "Belarus", Value = 6 });
        result.Add(new PieChartItem { Name = "USA", Value = 4 });
        return Json(new { Countries = result }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
public class PieChartItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Ну и в представлении `CreateChart` введены два скрипта:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     // Подгружаем API
      google.load('visualization', '1.0', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
        // Устанавливаем callback
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
       function drawChart() {
             var options = {
             'title': 'Blog Visitors',
              'width': 400,
               'height': 300
           };
         var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
           data.addColumn('string', 'Country');
          data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');

            $.getJSON('@Url.Action("CreateChart", "Chart")', null,
                                                        function (result) {
               if (result.Countries.length) {
                 $.each(result.Countries, function (index, c) {
                     data.addRow(
                         [c.Name, c.Value]
                      );
                    });
                 // Отрисовка диаграммы
                   var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(
                                        document.getElementById('n'));
                  chart.draw(data, options);
               };
          });
       }
</script>
<div id="n"></div>
```

Мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы такой график отображался, когда я нажимаю на кнопку,. Если просто открыть на сайте, то диаграмма работает, а вот с отображением по кнопке - заминка. С помощью Ajax.BeginForm добиться результата не удалось. Вот мои попытки в другом представлении:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateChart", "Chart", 
                  new AjaxOptions(){}))

{
    <input type="submit" value="Показать график"/>
}
```

Пытался так же проделать в JQuery, но  в результате выводится только текст, а не диаграмма

```
<input type='button' id="submit" value='Отобразить' />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#submit').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#n').load('@Url.Action("CreateChart", "Chart")')
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Вот похожая проблема, может быть поможет http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299626/how-to-draw-a-google-pie-chart-only-on-a-click-event-using-javascript-jquery